# flutter dart analyzer could not be started

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-analyzer

VSCode is giving me this error that my dart analyzer could not be started. Everything was working fine some days ago.I have tried to restart it but to no avail and I cant run my project.Any work around on how to fix this issue?
[image]

The log output

```
Sun Jul 14 2019 [16:51:11 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)] Log file started
[4:51:11 PM] [General] [Info] Searching for SDKs...
[4:51:11 PM] [General] [Info] Environment PATH:
[4:51:11 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5
[4:51:11 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
[4:51:11 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\system32
[4:51:11 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows
[4:51:11 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
```

See full log here [HERE](https://pastebin.com/UiN8ju7J).

Comment: what does the log look like?

Comment: Whenever you run VSCode it may take a while since the IDE recognizes the code as being .dart code. I have the same problem if exactly after starting the IDE I begin codding. Unfortunately I don't have an answer for this, but just out of curiosity; doesn't your IDE recognize .dart files after a while?

Comment: @pskink I have added a link to the log since its too.

Comment: what is the value of `FLUTTER_ROOT` environment variable?

Comment: @pskink ``C:\NoFlutterPerms\Git\flutter\.pub-cache\bin``

Comment: its wrong: it should be the root of your flutter distribution, it should point to the folder like https://github.com/flutter/flutter

Comment: ok, pointed it to `C:\NoFlutterPerms\Git\flutter\bin` but still the issue persists

Comment: its wrong again, it is not root of your flutter instalation

Comment: can you give more details on this as to what I should do?